# Google authentication screen inside application

Tags: android, google-account

I am using Google auth token for signing in my app. All is working fine but for the first time whenever a user sign in in my application it shows message token could not be found (because user hasnt given permisson to acces its gmail account ) and  it gives a notification on clicking on it a screen opens for asking to access my app some of there account data.So user have to again open my application  after giving permission.My question is this  can't I open that page for asking user to permit access inside application only? If yes then how?